# Is it now possible to spy on other person's iPhone using microphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, microphone

There is this app on the Appstore "Find My Kid" and "Chat with parents". They allow to the first app to start listening to microphone of the second app even without notification. Even when the app is in the background and the screen is off.

So I wonder: How does the app do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking *how/why Apple does something is outside the scope of what can be asked as defined in the [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).*

Answer (score 6):

I think the incorrect part of your question is the word 'spy'.  No, it's not possible to spy or listen to an iPhone's microphone without a notification or without the users consent.

I'm not a developer of these apps but I am an iOS developer with a few apps in the App Store so I'm familiar with the iPhone's API's and App Store review process.  Apple does not provide a way to secretly listen to another device

From reading [their product page description](https://web.archive.org/web/20221007061649/https://findmykids.org/en/), the 'listening' is done using a chat application or Messages.  The app starts recording and then sends the recording to the parents via chat.  It might work different in Android but for iOS that's what it looks like it's doing.  The image below specifically calls out "Android/GPS watch".

[image]
<sub>(source: [findmykids.org](https://findmykids.org/img/apps-new-screen3-eng.jpg?v2))</sub>

There doesn't appear to be anything 'secret' or in violation of Apple's app guidelines in these apps.  The wording on the app's App Store description is vague regarding how they do what they claim.

Comment: I didn't say there was no consent. But consent can be faked. There is no notification or other interface sign, at least when the screen is off. The other party installs the  "Chat with parents" and grants microphone permission. As soon as he did it, he can turn off the screen and has no idea if he is beeing listened to. Anyone with your device can install this app on your phone and spy on you. I tested it this morning. You should check facts before speaking with such confidence about something you read in the app description.

Comment: @RealNmae “*Anyone with your device*” - Not necessarily. They would also need to be able to unlock your device. Physical security and restrictions imposed by the OS work together to secure your device. But if I can unlock your device, I could install my developer certificate on it and upload any old app I’ve created, whether it complies with Apple’s App Store guidelines or not.

Comment: @RealNmae I can speak with confidence about it because I work with the Apple API's and have a very good idea what Apple allows an app to do.  Apple does not permit "anyone" to listen to your device microphone. Both parties, the parent and the child, must install something, agree to allow the app to use the mic to record, and agree to use of GPS, It's not something *anyone* can install any more than they can install any other app if they have your device.

Answer (score 1):

Despite not being an iOS native app developer a quick google shows that the combination of the microphone permission with the (static) [background execution audio permission](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) allows an app to record in the background. I assume this means Apple does ensure this permission isn't completely misgranted during the review process, *but* it's mixed with the permission to play audio in the background.

Just out of interest: In contrast since Android Pie (and Android Oreo to a lesser extent) Google will [only return a silent stream whilst an app is in background mode](https://www.theverge.com/2018/3/7/17091104/android-p-prevents-apps-using-mic-camera-idle-background).

Comment: Still it is unclear to me, how you could wake up the app to execute any code. Even with audio background mode, it would mean that iPhone never goes to sleep to receive notification to start the process of recording or sound alert.